# GAMS listing file in Promo API

Tags: pyomo, gams-math

I'm running the [GAMS/Pyomo API](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/pyomo-forum/NrYDDzhEL4g/-3E8ODK5BAAJ) for the first time.  The GAMS output says there was a problem during solve, and to check the listing file for details.  But I can't find the listing file.

I searched my entire MacBook for any *.lst files, and nothing.  So my main question is, where does GAMS spit out a listing file when it is called from the Promo API?  Is it in some temporary directory that my terminal can't search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the solve with the keepfiles=True flag turned on

Comment: Thanks much!  As soon as I did that, I see them in the folder that the GAMS output lists for the GDX file.  In my case:  /private/var/folders/k6/x9fjvpnx7yggqx6x7002p2q40000gn/T/tmpkg5iMl/